# Java socks4 client

Tags: java, socks

Java.net.Proxy supports socks5, is there a way to support socks4 as well? third party library is ok too.

Answer (score 1):

java.net.Proxy SHOULD support SOCKSv4 but doesn't in either OpenJDK6 or OpenJDK7. I am planning to file a bug.

But the SOCKSv4 code is already there and can be turned on.

Use reflection to pull out the impl field in a java.net.Socket object. Cast that object to java.net.SocksSocketImpl. Use reflection to set the useV4 boolean field in this object to true.

Then connect and it should use SOCKSv4.

Comment: @Zombies - how so?  Surely this issue predates any possible influence of Oracle culture on the Java team.

Comment: Actually Oracle has been influencing java for some time, at least/best democratically, but now they have free reign.